# How to move the scroll position on the bottom of prepended elements jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling to find a way to move my scroll position on the bottom of some elements that i've prepended in html.

This is the code i use to prepend my data:

```
var id = '#posts'+(yy-2);
$.get('page-'+(yy-1) , function(data){
     var content = $(data).find(id);
     $('#container').prepend(content);                           
});
```

I have to move the scroll position under 'content'.
I've tried adding:

```
$('html, body').scrollTop('#posts'+(yy-1));
```

But it doesn't do anything

Comment: Check `scrollIntoView` method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: Do you mean move the _bottom of your viewport_ to the bottom of the element? The scroll position is the top of the view port; if you align _that_ to the bottom of some element, the element would be off-screen. What have you tried? Google yields this, for example: [How do I get an element to scroll into view, using jQuery?](/q/4884839/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon when i click a button this function get started and it prepends some elements to my existing elements, the thing is that when i prepend those elements my scroll position stays on top of the prepended elements, but i need to get moved on the bottom of those elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question *"How to move the scroll position on the bottom of prepended elements in jquery?"*

https://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/

`.scrollTop( value )` Returns: jQuery

> Description: Set the current vertical position of the scroll bar for
> each of the set of matched elements.
>
> ```
> scrollTop( value )
>     value
>     Type: Number
>     A number indicating the new position to set the scroll bar to.
> ```
>
> The vertical scroll position is the same as the number of pixels that
> are hidden from view above the scrollable area. Setting the scrollTop
> positions the vertical scroll of each matched element.

In other words you are setting the scrollbar of a ***scrollable element***. Since your `#container` is expected to contain the posts with no overflow hidden, that's not strictly a scrollable area and your only one is the whole window (html).

When you did `$('html, body').scrollTop('#posts'+(yy-1));` it was equivalent to actually doing this `$('html').scrollTop(0)`.

But a working strategy might be to get the `position.y` and `height` of the element just prepended, and set the scrollbar to a number being the sum of those two values.

```
  const $post = createPost();  
  
  $('#posts').prepend($post);                           
 
  //y = $post vertical position
  const y = $post.position().top;
  //h = $post height
  const h = $post.height();
  
  //scroll the scrollable area to y+h (bottom of the latest div prepended)
  $('html').scrollTop(y+h);
```

I made a demo where you have a posts container `#posts` and a button at the bottom that will prepend a new post at the beginning of the list, and one moment later will move the window scroll position to the *"bottom of the prepended element"*.

***But confused...***

I'm still a bit confused on why you needed to scroll ***at the bottom*** of the latest prepended post. It doesn't click to me and that's why I quoted your textual question to my proposed solution.

```js
function createPost(){
  const $post = $('<div>');
  $post.addClass('post');
  const i = $('#posts > .post').length;
  const body = `This is a dynamic post #${i+1}`;
  $post.text(body);  
  return $post;
}

function prependPost(){
  const $post = createPost();  
  
  $('#posts').prepend($post);                           
 
  //y = $post vertical position
  const y = $post.position().top;
  //h = $post height
  const h = $post.height();
  
  //scroll the scrollable area to y+h (bottom of the latest div prepended)
  $('html').scrollTop(y+h);
}
```

```css
body{
  padding: 3em;
}

h1{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4rem;
  border-bottom: solid 3px lightgray;
}

#posts{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
  
  border: dashed 3px lightgray;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;    
}

.post{
  height: 10em;
  border: solid 1px lightgray;    
  padding: 1em;
}

button{
  padding: 1em 1em;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Posts:</h1>

<div id="posts">
  <div class="post">This is a static post #1</div>
  <div class="post">This is a static post #2</div>
  <div class="post">This is a static post #3</div>
</div>

<button
  type="button"
  onclick="prependPost();">PREPEND POST</button>
```

Comment: this is exactly what i needed, my button will be on top of the posts, this will be needed for all the pages that are different from page1, so if a user goes from an external link to page2 you can see the posts from page 1 clicking the button on top, but wanting to give an idea of scroll i needed that my prepended posts must be on the top of the view, so the user can scroll up having the prepended posts

Comment: ok then, glad it worked as expected